# How to convert a float to int along with its decimals considered?

Tags: java

For example, I am having 12.12 float value I want it to become 1212 an integer value

If I am having 156.2345 I want it to be 1562345.

I have searched a lot but found only rounding and casting to int but no answer for my question.

Moreover, if we have 12.12000 then also **I should be getting 1212 only but not 1212000**.

The problem is I will be reading double or float from stdinput and I have to convert that to appropriate int as per above rules

Tried  `Float.intValue()` among others, but that gives 12 only

Comment: An `int` can't hold decimal values.

Comment: Convert that number into String, remove decimal, convert back to integer. Now think about the range of integer or long and take decision accordingly.

Comment: A `float` does not store a fixed number of decimal places, so it's not clear exactly how this could work that would actually be useful for you. For example, I imagine you wouldn't want `0.1` to return `100000001`, but I don't see a good way to avoid that.

Comment: I want 0.1 to return 1

Comment: @Naseer: I know that's what you want, but that's not what you will get, because of the way 0.1 is stored as a `float` internally.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sure @halfer read the post ,I will not repeat and Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following:

```
floatValue.toString().replaceAll("[0]*$", "").replace(".", "");
```

First replace will remove all trailing 0s from the float value while second replace will remove the `dot`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure it's a good idea to do this but you can do

```
double d = 12.12;
long n = Long.parseLong(BigDecimal.valueOf(d).toString().replaceAll("[.,]", ""));
```

This will drop any decimal places. You can use `float` and `int` instead.

If you want `1.0` to be `1` instead of `10`, and `10.0` to be `1` instead of `10`or `100` you can add

```
.replaceAll("[0]*$", "")
```

> Tried Float.intValue() among others, But that gives 12 only

As it should. `intValue` returns the value as an `int` rounded down.

Comment: There's still the scientific notation (produced by `toString`) that needs to be covered here. This won't work with `"3.4028235E38"` (`Float.MAX_VALUE`).

Comment: @ernest_k good point. Switched to BigDecimal for `E10`, but this won't help for `E38` given the range of `long` or `int` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach that multiplies the number by 10 until the remainder division by 1 yields 0:

```
static long toLong(double d) {
    if (d % 1 != 0) {
        return toLong(d * 10);
    }

    return (long) d;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Integer.parseInt(Float.toString(value).replaceAll(Pattern.quote("."), ""));
```

The shortest and safe code.
replaceAll() takes regex as argument, so you must use Pattern.quote();

Integer.parseInt(): Parses an Integer from String. (ex: "123" -> (int)123)

Float.toString(): Converts a Float to String. (ex: 12.34 -> "1234")

replaceAll(String regex, String change_to): Replace all 'regex' to change_to.